# Are HTTP Status code descriptions used?

Tags: http

Is the description component of a HTTP status code used? For example, in the HTTP response '200 OK', is the OK (i.e. the description) ever used? Or is it just for humans to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the "reason phrase" is purely there for humans to read. Nothing should be using it programmatically - especially because in [HTTP/2, it's been eliminated](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#HttpResponse):

> HTTP/2 does not define a way to carry the version or reason phrase that is included in an HTTP/1.1 status line.

Answer (score 0):

The status code is often used. For example, if you are using AJAX, you will most likely check the HTTP status code before using the data returned.

However the description is just for humans as computers recognize the status code and what it entails without the description.

Answer (score 0):

The description is a standard message associated with the code itself to get a quick description of the code. It is used for a diagnostic, along with its full description wich can be found on the https status code list. So, it is not "used" as i think you're implying, but indeed only used for diagnostic by humans

> The data sections of messages Error, Forward and redirection responses may be used to contain human-readable diagnostic information.